# problem with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog, load

I have a partial view with a dropdown (with `Paid and unpaid` as options) and a button. 
I am loading this partial view using jquery load, when the user click `Paid/Unpaid List link` in the sub menu of a page.

When i select Paid in dropdown and click the button, it shows the list of paid customers in the jquery dialog and if i select Unpaid and click button, it shows unpaid customers in the jquery dialog.

I am writing the following code for the dialog:

```
 $('#customers').dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                //populate table
                var p_option = $('#d_PaidUnPaid option:selected').val();
                if (p_option  == 'PAID') {
                    $("#customercontent").html('');
                    //$("#customercontent").load("/Customer/Paid");
                }
                else if (p_option  == 'UNPAID') {
                    $("#customercontent").html('');
                    //$("#customercontent").load("/Customer/Unpaid");
                }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                //do nothing
            },
            height: 500,
            width: 550,
            modal: true
        });
```

For the first time, i am getting the list correctly in the jquery dialog, but when i click the `Paid/Unpaid List link` again and select Unpaid in the dropdown and click the button, it shows the previos loaded content in the jquery dialog.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding no-caching option to jQuery AJAX.  I had problems with the load() function (and IE) where cached results would always be shown.
To change the setting for all jQuery AJAX requests do

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Comment: where should i need to add this line? before loading the partial view? –

Comment: even right before $('#customers').dialog({... should suffice.  If you have any type of javascript bootstrap file, that's where it would normally go

Comment: i have called in the click event of the button before opening dialog, but still the problem occurs

Comment: Here is the click event of the button added in $(document).ready: $('#b_customers').click(function(e) { $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); $('#customers').dialog('open'); });

Answer (score 3):

I hope Im not too late to come up with correct answer. I had the same problem and I solved it with following ajax settings.

```
open: function () {
      jQuery.ajaxSetup({
             cache: false
       });
       //populate table or do what you want...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add this after open:

```
$('#customers').empty().remove();
```

Example:

```
    open: function(event, ui) {
              //populate table
              var p_option = $('#d_PaidUnPaid option:selected').val();
              if (p_option  == 'PAID') {
                  $("#customercontent").html('');
                  //$("#customercontent").load("/Customer/Paid");
              }
              else if (p_option  == 'UNPAID') {
                  $("#customercontent").html('');
                  //$("#customercontent").load("/Customer/Unpaid");
              }

              $('#customers').empty().remove();

          },
```